# How to disable code conditionally

Tags: php, macros

I'm a C/C++ Programmer new to PHP. 
In C/C++, I often add code to my project (e.g. debugging output) that will be active only if a specific macro is defined. So, I'm able to "switch on / switch off" some code by defining / removing the macro definition inside a central header file.

E.g. in the header file:

```
#define ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
```

and anywhere in the code where it is useful:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
    print_debug_output ( ... );
#endif
```

So to disable the print-debug_output calls (or anything else), I only need to comment out the #define inside the header file.

Is there some equivalent in PHP?

At first, I want to use FirePHP for debugging output on my test system, but disable it as soon as I put the code on the server. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Easiest approach is to define a constant such as `DEBUG_ENABLED` then use an `if (DEBUG_ENABLED)` to test whether to log or not; if it makes things easier, DEBUG_ENABLED can be defined in a config file

Comment: set a variable on your ini file and check its on or off whereever you are going to use Firephp to debug..

Comment: You'll be _much_ better off putting that switch inside the equivalent of your print_debug_output function (in the example in the question) instead of littering `if (DEBUG)` statements throughout your codebase.

Comment: Always remind echo $var; var_dump($var); which are always useful (even though someone will yell at me). What Mark said is indeed the most efficient / easiest. If you need something more complex, take a look at exceptions. Also, as the answers aren't really correct, debug SHOULD always be a constant and not a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use native PHP function http://www.php.net/define

```
//Place the below line to your first loading file or any preferred place;
define("ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT", true); //Or false;

//Then use it anywhere:
if( ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT )
    print_r($my_debug_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd use the most basic way:

```
$debug = SOME_CONDITIONAL;

if ($debug) { 
    // display errors/warnings/notices in output
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
}
```

then as expected in your main code:

```
if ($debug) { 
    /* debugging code */
}
```

I'm aware this is pretty gross, but it's nice and clear.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to place such variable in the globals:

```
$GLOBALS['ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT'] = true;
```

and then

```
if (isset($GLOBALS['ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT'])){
  echo ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global debug function like:

```
// $level = 0 nothing - 9 alert with email
function debug($str, $level = 1) {
    // Uncomment the following line in NO_DEBUG mode:
    //return;

    switch ($level) {
        case 9:
            //mail();
        case 8:
        case 7:
        case 5:
            // file_put_contents(); // or whatever
        case 3:
            echo $str, PHP_EOL;
        case 2:
        case 1:
        case 0: break;
    }
}
```

You can put in different levels and say, if its lvl 9 it sends a mail, writes a log and echos to screen. on lvl 5 you only want write a log and print to screen (that's why I don't break upon every case).

With a function like taht you don't have to wrap

```
if (defined('ENABLE_DEBUG')) {
    //...
}
```

arround every debug message but instead simply use `debug('test string');`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use constants in php :

```
<?php 
  define('DEBUG', true);
```

And you can create a function to display things only if `DEBUG` is true

```
<?php

  function debug($obj)
  {
    if (DEBUG)
    {
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($obj);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
  }
```

I personally use a function `debug($obj, $label)` which send this to `Firephp` to have the debug info in the firebug console